# Rails using enum type as a value for an attribute

Tags: ruby, enums, model, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is my model defination:

```
class OrderFrequency < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "order_frequencies"
  enum frequency_unit: { hour: 1}

end
```

and migration

```
class CreateOrderFrequencies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :order_frequencies do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.integer :unit
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So how do I assign `unit` attribute with enum of `frequency_unit`?

I cannot do

```
OrderFrequency.create(value: 'value 123', unit: OrderFrequency.frequency_unit.hour)
```

What is the correct way to use `frequency_unit` enum for the unit attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the official documentation for `ActiveRecord::Enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) -- the idea isn't to have two attribute names (`unit` and `frequency_unit`); you should only have *one*. (After all, it's the same thing!)

Let's change your model to:

```
class OrderFrequency < ApplicationRecord
  # Note: Specifying the (default) table_name here is also redundant
  enum unit: { hour: 1 }
end
```

Now you can create a record via:

```
OrderFrequency.create(
  value: 'value 123',
  unit: OrderFrequency.units['hour']
)
```

Or even (!!) by just writing:

```
OrderFrequency.create(
  value: 'value 123',
  unit: 'hour'
)
```

---

The key idea with `ActiveRecord::Enum` is that *in the database* the value is stored as an integer, but *in the application* (99% of the time) you can work with human-friendly `String`s - i.e. `"hour"` rather than `1`.

If for some reason you need to retrieve a list of all known `unit`s, you can do this with:

```
OrderFrequency.units.keys #=> ['hour']
```